# How to set up a course structure in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to make an app for my school with Swift, but I´m struggling with one feature.

Students should be able to sign up for classes (each class has 16 free spots) and I don´t know how to set up the database. I started using Firebase for a signing in feature.

What would you recommend for my course structure and signing up for classes? Should I use Firebase or something else? How do I set up my database that a course is limited to 16 participants?

Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: Firebase can handle this. However, this question is not really appropriate for this forum. Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Use Core Data. It gets a lot of bad press, but it's perfect for something like this. Create a `Student` entity, with whatever properties `Student`s have, then define a `Course` (not `Class`) entity, with a many-to-many relationship between `Student`s and `Course`s. Then set 16 as the limit of students in the `Course` -> `Student` relationship.

Comment: How would you propose multiple user access to the the data? Also, if a student signs up for a class, how would the other students be notified that a class is now full? How would you handle concurrent updates or prevent race conditions with Core Data?